# Styling a <select> on iOS

Tags: ios, css, html, safari, mobile-safari

I'm developing a web-app for both *Android* and *iOS*.

I have encountered a problem with the styling of the app.

For some reason, styles applied to a `<select>` won't display on `MobileSafari` (aka iOS WebView)

CSS:

```
p,
input,
select,
option,
button {
    font-family: Arial, ArialHebrew, sans-serif;
    font-size: x-large;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 1vh;
    padding: 1vh;
}

input,
select,
option,
button {
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 1vh;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

How i want it to look (Chrome, Android):

[image: How I Want It To Look]

How it looks (MobileSafari, iOS):

[image: How It Looks]

What do i need to change in my CSS to apply the style to the `<select>`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The quick & easy fix is to apply `-webkit-appearance: none`. However, you might quickly notice your element has lost the `arrow` to indicate it's a `<select>` element.

To address this, one workaround is to wrap your element with a div and mimic the arrow using CSS content.

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d6jhpo7v/

And the fiddle in iOS simulator:

[image]